# Angular 4 - pass an array to directive without converting it to string

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives

I have an array in my component.ts:

```
labels: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

and need to pass it to a directive in my template. 
if I try this:

```
<app-charts [valueArray] = "['a','b','c']" </app-charts>
```

it's working but I want to pass in the variable. Something like this:

```
<app-charts [valueArray] = {{labels}} </app-charts>
```

but it's not working.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `{{}}` when you have `[]`. `[]` already ensures that Angular will treat the value as expression:

```
[valueArray]="labels"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.